# Name for functions that are anti-symmetric about $y=x$

Tags: terminology, involutions

Even functions are functions that are symmetric about the $Y$-axis, and odd functions are functions that are symmetric about the origin.  Functions that are symmetric about $y=x$ ($y=f(x)$ implies $x=f(y)$) are involutions, i.e. functions that are their own inverse.

Is there a special name for functions that are *anti-symmetric* about $y=x$?  In other words, is there a name for the property:  If $y=f(x)$ and $x=f(y)$ then $x=y$?  The word *anti-involution* seems to be in use, but according to Wikipedia it has a rather technical definition in terms of antihomomorphisms and doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Odd functions are symmetric about the origin.

Comment: You are asking if $f(f(x))=x,$ then $f(x)=x.$ There are plenty such functions. Any function with $f(x)\geq x$ for all $x$ works. For example, $f(x)=x+1,$ or $f(x)=x+g(x)^2$ for any real function $g(x).$

Comment: @Bey Ah, you're right, I'll edit that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that's a much cleaner equivalent condition, thanks!

Comment: @Piquito The condition isn't $f(x)=x$ -- it's *if* $f(f(x))=x$ *then* $f(x)=x$.  i.e. the function is nowhere involutive.  $f(x)=x+1$ is a good example, whereas $f(x)=-x+1$ is a good non-example ($f(f(0))=0$, yet $f(0) \ne 0$).

Comment: @CalebK:-Okay, thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any monotonic increasing function works. If $f(x)<x$ then $f(f(x))\leq f(x)<x,$ so $f(f(x))\neq x.$ Similarly, $f(x)>x,$ then $f(f(x))\geq f(x)>x,$ so again $f(f(x))\neq x.$ You don't need $f$ to be strictly monotonic.

Also, any $f$ such that $f(x)\geq x$ for all $x.$ If $f(x)\neq x,$ then $f(x)>x$ and $f(f(x))\geq f(x)>x.$ This includes functions like $f(x)=x+x^2,$ or more generally $f(x)=x+g(x)^2,$ for any function $g,$ which are not strictly increasing.

Similarly, if $f(x)\leq x$ for all $x,$ then when $f(x)\neq x$ we get $f(x)<x$ and thus $f(f(x))\leq f(x)<x.$ So this includes functions like $f(x)=x-g(x)^2.$

$x+g(x)^2$ and $x-g(x)^2$ allows solutions to $g(x)=0,$ so we can get functions $f$ with arbitrary sets of solutions to $f(x)=0.$ Given any closed $C\subseteq\mathbb R,$ we can find continuous $g$ with $C=\{x\mid g(x)=0\}$ and then $C=\{x\mid f(x)=x\}.$

There are a lot of such functions.

Given a general $f,$ if $h(x)=f(x)-x,$ your condition $f(f(x))=x$ becomes $h(x+h(x))+h(x)=0$ so you want $$h(x+h(x))+h(x)=0\implies h(x)=0.\tag1$$

It is worth considering what $(1)$ means if $f$ is monotonic increasing.

If $h$ is differentiable, monotonicity of $f$ means $h'(x)\neq -2$ for all $x.$ Then $h(x+h(x))=h(x)+h'(c)h(x)$ for some $c$ in $(x,x+h(x)).$ So $0=h(x+h(x))+h(x)=(2+h'(c))h(x).$ But $2+h'(c)\neq 0,$ so this means $h(x)=0.$

So we can apparently use any $h(x)$ differentiable such that for all $x,$ $h'(x)\neq -2.$ So this means and differentiable $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)\neq -1.$

> If $f$ is differentiable, and $f'(x)\neq -1$ for all $x,$ we have $f(f(x))=x$ if and only if $f(x)=x.$
>
> Proven directly: If $u=f(x)$ and $u\neq x,$ then $f(u)=x$ and $u-x=f(x)-f(u)=f'(c)(x-u)$ for some $c$ between $u$ and $x.$ But $f'(c)\neq -1,$ this isn't possible.

So this includes a lot of functions which decrease "too quickly," like $f(x)=-2x.$

---

[Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) says that any function which is the derivative of another satisfies the intermediate value property, so if $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\neq -1$ for all $x,$ then either $f'(x)<-1$ for all $x$ or $f'(x)>-1$ for all $x.$

If course, there are $f$ with some $f'(x)=-1$ which satisfy this condition. For example, when $f(x)=-(x+x^3).$ Then $f'(0)=-1,$ but $f(f(x))=x$ still implies $f(x)=x.$ This is because while $f'(0)=-1,$ there is no $u\neq v$ with $f(u)-f(v)=v-u,$ because the function $f$ crosses the tangent at $x=0.$

---

Of course, our mean value condition on $u,v$ excluded $f(u)+u=f(v)+v$ when $u\neq v,$ which is stronger than excluding $f(u)=v, f(v)=u.$

For example, $f(x)=x^2-x$ has $f(f(x))-x = x^4-2x^3,$ so the roots of $f(f(x))=x$ are $x=0,2$ but $f(0)=0, f(2)=2.$ So $f$ has your property, but $f(x)+x = f(-x)+(-x)=x^2,$ so $f$ has infinitely many pairs $u\neq v$ with $f(u)+u=f(v)+v$ but no such pair with $f(u)=v$ and $f(v)=u.$

Comment: Ah, this is all really interesting.  And in fact the function I'm dealing with does have $f(x) \geq x$ for all $x$, which is probably the property I should state instead.  But... I suppose there isn't an existing special name for this kind of function?

Comment: Unless someone happens to know if there's a word for it, I'm accepting this answer.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Thomas!

Comment: I'd doubt there is a word for it. It seems a somewhat artificial condition which might not have much use, and we name things because we want to talk about it, often either because they are useful or they somehow have an aesthetic appeal.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be asking if I didn't have a use for it :-)  I'm dealing with a function that represents forward propagation in a feed-forward neural network, and I'm looking to write down the properties of that function.  Since the neural network is feed-forward, some sort of 'acyclic'/'antisymmetric' property needs so show up somewhere.  But $f(x) \geq x$ happens to hold, and I have a weakened monotonicity condition, so probably this antisymmetry thing will turn out not to be the star of the show.

Comment: I guess I had hoped that somebody else ran into this condition as well (it's not so artificial from my point of view), but I get your point -- it follows from big-name properties like 'monotonically increasing'.

Comment: But as you've already mentioned, your functions satisfy the stronger $f(x)\geq x.$ I'd certainly suspect that those functions have a name. @CalebK

Comment: Essentially, your functions have the property that the graph is always on or above the function $f(x)=x,$ so the antisymmetry fact is a consequence of the much stronger fact that the graph contains no points strictly below $f(x)=x.$ @CalebK

Answer (score -1):

The function  $f^{-1}(x)$ and f(x) are symmetric to the line y=x and if $y=f(x) ->  x=f^{-1}(y)$
is that what you mean?Example $f(x)=x^2, x>=0 and  f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ are symmetric to y=x

Comment: This is not the question. As a general rule, if you have to ask "Is that why you mean?" you should try to clarify the question before you answer.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right!